# Как в Android корректно снять Bitmap с view элемента?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь взять bitmap с элемента, используя метод который ранее не подводил:

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
        view.layout(0, 0, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)

view.draw(canvas)
```

Но сейчас что-то не то получилось. Слева скрин, справа то что вернулось в bitmap. Что я делаю не так?)

Comment: Я бы начал с самого view, с его метода отрисовки. Что-то он там не так вычисляет и не то рисует. Справа даже сегментов некоторых не хватает. А это код похоже что Ок.

Comment: а где вы вызываете view.measure? похоже из-за этого происходит рассинхронизация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коллеги Eugene Krivenja и Style-7 натолкнули меня на верное решение. Все оказалось даже очень просто, в onDraw я использовал width.toFloat() и height.toFloat(), а нужно было закешировать их значения в методе onSizeChanged, и проблема решена!